# Automating phpmyadmin installation

Tags: command-line, scripts, phpmyadmin, debconf

I am using the following commands to install phpmyadmin and the install is getting interrupted...

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/debconfig-install boolean true"
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-user string root"
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass password root"
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password root"
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password root"
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-websever multiselect apache2"
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/database-type select mysql"
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/setup-password password root"
```

However when I am using the following I found online it's installing perfectly fine...

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/reconfigure-webserver multiselect apache2"  
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true"  
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-user string root"  
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/admin-pass password root"  
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/mysql/app-pass password root"  
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/app-password-confirm password root"
```

I am interested to find out what I am doing wrong in the first example to make the automated install fail, and how I can find out what debconf-set-selections are required for other software installations? I know I can find out all the selections for a specific package by doing

```
sudo debconf-get-selections | grep phpmyadmin
```

However that does not show me only the required ones to achieve an automated installation.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line of your commands you have an extra "e" in the dbconfig-install command:

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/debconfig-install boolean true"
```

Should be:

```
debconf-set-selections <<< "phpmyadmin phpmyadmin/dbconfig-install boolean true"
```

Hope this helps.